# Initializing map from JSON response

Tags: typescript

I have data from API in a format where I receive JSON with entries as map with number keys. However I can't assign my result to data structure below as compiler complains that Map methods are missing for obvious reason.

```
entryContainer = {
    entries: {
        1: {
            title: 'title 1'
        },
        2: {
          title: 'title 2'
        }
}

export interface EntryContainer {
    entries: Map<number, Entry>;
}

export interface Entry {
    title: string;
}

// doesn't work
let result: EntryContainer = entryContainer;
```

Is there any elegant way how to initialize Entrycontainer with data received in above-mentioned format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entries` on the data you're receiving isn't a `Map`, so you'll have to create a `Map`.

The good news is that this is trivially easy with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and `new Map`:

```
let result: EntryContainer = {
    entries: new Map(Object.entries(entryContainer.entries).map(([key, value]) => [+key, value]))
};
```

That:

- Uses `Object.entries` to get an array of `[string, string]`.
- Uses `map` to get an array of `[number, string]` instead. (Remember that even though the keys in your `entryContainer` object are written as numeric literals, keys in objects are always either strings or Symbols.)
- Takes the resulting array of `[number, string]` and creates the `entries` map
- Creates the `EntryContainer` wrapper around `entries

You'll need to ensure that your `target` and/or `lib` options are set correctly. `Map`, of course, is ES2015. `Object.entries` is ES2017.